# Recursive algorithm to fill increasing array { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ... }

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

I have the following task:

> Give a recursive algorithm for filling an array like this: *one 1, two 2, tree 3, four 4, ... ,n n.*

For example, with `n = 4` the array is supposed to look like:

```
{ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 }
```

My attempt is

```
Function filling(T, k, n)

if (n = 0) do return 1 
else if (0 <= k) do filling (T, n - k + 1, n);
     else filling(T, k, n - 1);
     fi
fi
```

with `filling(T, k, n)`

- `k`: block start case of number n,
- `n`: number,
- `T`: array

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be recursive?

Comment: What language are you required to use?

Comment: I write it with algorithm structure, I want it with C++

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Doesnt your current attempt work? What is its output?

Comment: I ask if result of this function is correct because I'm Still beginner in programming I still learning c+.

Comment: Have you tried running your function? What does it return? Does it look correct to you?

Comment: no I didn't tried running can you do it for me please

Comment: If you have no working C++ compiler you can write and test your program at one of several online compiler/debugger services, e.g. the GDB online Debugger https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: If the answer given answers your question and solves your problem, you can mark it as 'accepted', so that others will know it does. Of course there is no hurry – you may well wait some time to see if better answer appears. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in our [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly show, the function needs an array `T`, a starting index `k` of the area to fill, and a size of the task `n`, i.e. a maximum number for filling.

The algorithm can be described like this:

> if `n` is zero, return;
> otherwise:
>
> > perform filling from `1` till `n-1`,
> > then append `n` items of value `n`

The question arises, how should the last line know *where* it should start adding.

One simple answer is: the routine may return the index one past the filled area:

```
size_t filling(int T[], size_t k, size_t n)
{
    if (n != 0)
    {
        k = filling(T, k, n - 1);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            T[k + i] = n;
    }
    return k + n;
}
```

Make sure your array is at least `n*(n+1)/2` items long, so that you don't overrun it.

Comment: Thanks @CiaPan ,@Zabuzard and all for  efforts it is really appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of two things here:

- Number of digits to be insert in the array starting from `1`, and
- Count of a digit (which should be equal to digit itself) when inserting it in the array.

Since, the algorithm should be implemented using recursion, we should know the terminating condition of recursion.

Algorithm:

- Insert digit in array.
- Check if the count of digit inserted in array is equal to digit or not:

  - If count == digit then reset the count to `0` and increase digit by `1`.
  - If count < digit go to step `1`.
- If digit to be inserted in array is greater than `n`, terminate the recursion.

Implementation in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void filling (std::vector <int>& arr, int k, int n) {
    static int c;

    if (c >= n) {
        c = 0;
        return;
    }

    if (k <= c) {
        k = k + 1;
        arr.push_back(c + 1);
    } else {
        k = 0;
        c = c + 1;
    }

    filling (arr, k, n);
}

int main() {
    std::vector <int> arr;

    int n;

    std::cout << "Enter a number:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;

    filling (arr, 0, n);

    for (const auto& x : arr) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Enter a number:
5
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 

# ./a.out
Enter a number:
10
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 

# ./a.out
Enter a number:
1
1 

# ./a.out
Enter a number:
4
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help